# R Shiny Plots changing without update button being pressed

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to design a Shiny App where the user changes several inputs, then presses a "Plot" button to generate new visualizations. Currently, I have the a data object being generated in an eventReactive tied to the "Plot" button, with that data then getting fed into the renderPlot functions.

The framework seems to work, except that the plots will change whenever the inputs are changed. This often leads to errors in the plots, as different inputs load in different data. Pressing the "Plot" button after changing the inputs will cause the correct plots to render, but I'm trying to find a way to ensure that the plots don't change ever until that button is hit.

I believe the solution is a use of the "isolation" function, and I've tried that just about everywhere. However, none of these attempts have been successful. Below is a (simplified) setup of my code.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        # several selectInput options
        actionButton('plot', label = 'Plot')
    )
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput('outputPlot', height = '3in'),
    )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    plotData <- eventReactive(input$plot, {
        # load various data and organize into a list
        return(data.list)
    })
    
    outPutPlot <- renderPlot({
        plot.data <- plotData()
        # manipulate data based on the specific plot, then generate
        return(plot)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re right that you’d need to `isolate()` all reactive dependencies other
than `plotData()`. Without having a complete runnable example, it’s not
possible to point out where this might have gone wrong. However, it may be
easier to wrap the `renderPlot()` call in `bindEvent()`, which will isolate
everything. You just pass the expressions you want to depend on in other
arguments.

So try something like this:

```r
bindEvent(renderPlot({ ... }), plotData())
```